# How to Multiple Select by Data Description

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-4, multiple-select-query

I having trouble to selecting datas from my DB, could you please help me to solve these ;

these are my data in database :

```
id_abs     photo     date        time     desc    id_user
------------------------------------------------------------
1          p.png    2021-02-03   07.10    in      13
2          q.png    2021-02-03   18.20    out     13
3          r.png    2021-04-03   07.04    in      15
4          s.png    2021-04-03   18.30    out     15
5          t.png    2021-05-03   07.05    in      13
6          u.png    2021-05-03   18.10    out     13
```

and this is the table of output from DB that i want to select :

Nb : i want to select where id_user = 13

```
DATE         PHOTO_IN    PHOTO_OUT    IN     OUT
----------------------------------------------------------
2021-02-03   p.png       q.png        07.10  18.20
2021-02-05   t.png       u.png        07.05  18.10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **subquery** inside **query select** in your **Model**. You can try this instead

- Example Subquery in **Model**

```
    <?php
    
        namespace App\Models;
        
        use CodeIgniter\Database\BaseBuilder;
        use CodeIgniter\Model;
        
        class M_user extends Model {
            protected $table = 'user_absen as UB';
            protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    
            public function getData($user_id = 0) {
                $this->select('
                   (SELECT
                       UBX.date
                    FROM
                       user_absen UBX
                    WHERE
                       UBX.user_id = UB.user_id
                       AND UBX.date = UB.date
                    GROUP BY
                       UBX.user_id,
                       UBX.date) AS `DATE`,
                   (SELECT
                       UBX.photo
                    FROM
                       user_absen UBX
                    WHERE
                       UBX.user_id = UB.user_id
                       AND UBX.date = UB.date
                       AND UBX.desc = 'in'
                    GROUP BY
                       UBX.user_id,
                       UBX.date) AS `PHOTO_IN`,
                   (SELECT
                       UBX.photo
                    FROM
                       user_absen UBX
                    WHERE
                       UBX.user_id = UB.user_id
                       AND UBX.date = UB.date
                       AND UBX.desc = 'out'
                    GROUP BY
                       UBX.user_id,
                       UBX.date) AS `PHOTO_OUT`,
                    (SELECT
                       UBX.time
                    FROM
                       user_absen UBX
                    WHERE
                       UBX.user_id = UB.user_id
                       AND UBX.date = UB.date
                       AND UBX.desc = 'in'
                    GROUP BY
                       UBX.user_id,
                       UBX.date) AS `IN`,
                    (SELECT
                       UBX.time
                    FROM
                       user_absen UBX
                    WHERE
                       UBX.user_id = UB.user_id
                       AND UBX.date = UB.date
                       AND UBX.desc = 'in'
                    GROUP BY
                       UBX.user_id,
                       UBX.date) AS `OUT`
               ');

               $this->groupBy('UB.user_id, UB.date');
    
               if (isset($user_id) && $user_id != 0) {
                  $this->where('UB.user_id', $user_id);
               }
    
               // Default output as Array
               $this->get()->getResult(); 
            }
        }
    ?>
```

- **Controller**

```
    <?php
    
        namespace App\Controllers;
        
        use App\Controllers\BaseController;
        use App\Models\M_user;
    
        class ControllerPengadaan extends BaseController {
            protected $m_user;
    
            public function __construct() {
                $this->m_user = new M_user();
            }
            
            public function index() {
                $data['data_user'] = $this->m_user->getData(13);
                echo view('v_index', $data);
            }
        }
    ?>
```

- **View**

```
    v_index.php

    <table>
       <tr>
          <th>DATE</th>
          <th>PHOTO_IN</th>
          <th>PHOTO_OUT</th>
          <th>IN</th>
          <th>OUT</th>
       </tr>
       <?php
     
           foreach($data_user as $data) {
               echo '
                  <tr>
                    <td>'.$data['DATE'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$data['PHOTO_IN'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$data['PHOTO_OUT'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$data['IN'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$data['OUT'].'</td>
                  </tr>
               ';
           }      
    
       ?>
    </table>
```

I hope you are helped.

Comment: terima kasih :)

Comment: Sama Bro :) @eve